# The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages - issue with some app and RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just downloaded an app code from github and when I am trying to run the command `rails s`, I am getting this error -

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
```

This is specific to this app only, can someone tell me how to fix this ? I am using RVM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really sure what exactly your problem is. If you use rvm and have installed Rails with it, you may have to use

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

(version number may depend on your installation). Then you may or may have not a gemset with this. So:

```
bundle install
```

should install Rails gem in this gemset. Maybe use

```
rvmsudo bundle install
```

or just manually install the Rails gem. But this would partially depend on the Rails version expected by the app. There are other options, but this should mostly work.

For setting a version permanently you can use:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

For this to work you must have something like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in your ~/.bash_profile.

In addition you can have something like a .rvm folder in your project where you can set rvm options on a project level if you need to switch between versins often (didn't use this myself, but there should be docs on the rvm homepage)

Comment: btw, I have to do this all the time now (after logging in shell), can you tell me permanent solution for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 20):

In case anyone else has this problem, but the above doesn't work. Try running:

```
/bin/bash --login
```

then run

```
rvm use 2.0.0 #or whatever your version number is...
```

Comment: I just used the `/bin/bash --login` and everything started working.  For those out there who are wondering why this is necessary (like I was), I found this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/445015/193869

Answer (score 1):

I have use `/bin/bash --login` for my ubuntu on raspberry pi after getting the same error. It's working right now.