# Rails not recognizing commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a Rails project but when I issues commands such as rails s, or rails c from within the project directory I get:

`The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Do I need to set my path variable? Please help!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135612/the-program-rails-can-be-found-in-the-following-packages-issue-with-some-app solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the gems in your gemfile, using bundler. From the root of your app, type `bundle`. Next, run your commands using bundler, like `bundle exec rails c` or `bundle exec rails s`.

Comment: I had to install bundler. when I run bundle exec rails c, for example, I get: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0. So I installed ruby 2.0.0 with RVM and when I type rvm use 2.0.0 I get: RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
I am checking that info now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It took a while to find the run command as login checkbox in linux mint which I just installed. Now it works. Your suggestions led me to the solution. Thanks again