# rails and bundle command are not found in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am new to rails, and I have a very strange problem. I installed ruby on rails properly on my system and even have a running rails application on it.

But today when I cloned a project from git and tried to run commands like rails s and bundle install, they are not recognized, though when I run rake it works fine. I have other rails project which have created. these command are working fine there, I don't know what the problem is here. It is happening in all cloned projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the ruby gem executable directory to your system path using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ruby-2.1.2/bin
```

Comment: i did add this to my bashrc but it didnt help.. i getting all rails command available options when use rails anywhere in system but when in this dir it shows me this message The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages..* ruby-railties-3.2
* ruby-railties-4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
bundle install 
rails s
```

Comment: Getting this error... The program 'bundle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install bundler

Comment: isn't there something like i need to convert this project to rails project .. as in grails when we do import from git we need to first convert it to grails project ...

Comment: when u do ruby -v and rails -v do you get specific versions or not installed ?

Comment: no we dont have to convert it.
check your installed rails version and the version in your github project

Comment: when i do rails -v in this  it gives me ...The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages..* ruby-railties-3.2 * ruby-railties-4.0 ....but on ruy -v it shows  ruby 1.9.3p429 ...

Comment: and the version in github project ??

Comment: ok have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135612/the-program-rails-can-be-found-in-the-following-packages-issue-with-some-app

Comment: this project is on rails 4 ... and also i have rails 4  .. as when do rails -v in other dir .. it shows Rails 4.0.0

Comment: giving this ....The program 'bundle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install bundler

Comment: try the above link i have provided

Comment: tried that link ... but the same message is shown for both rails and bundle install ... dont know why are not working only here .. ruby version was changed to 1.9.3.. but next step bundle install giving the same error messgae..

Comment: so here the unexpected happens............ it stops working everywhere.... now had to find a solution :)

Comment: try changing back to initial rvm version or to the default version by "rvm reset"